# Как обратится к объекту, созданному в новом потоке?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Создаю в новом потоке объект, но ссылку для него хочу также иметь в главном потоке (что-то вроде параллельной инициализации), я думал сделать переменную `object` как `final`, но компилятору этого недостаточно, он предлагает конструкцию типа `final Object[] object = new Object[1]` и потом в этот массив добавить ссылку `object[0] = new Object()` из нового потока. Чем его не устроила переменная объявленная как финал? Или такая практика параллельной работы не приветствуется вообще? А как же к примеру в Swing отделить графический интерфейс от общего потока с сохранением связи между ними?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object object;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            object = new Object();
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, финальную переменную невозможно изменить.Во-вторых, видимость присваивания неволатильной переменной не гарантирована. В-третьих, у Swing есть специальные абстракции для многопоточности, не стоит работать с Thread напрямую.

Comment: Спасибо, все мне теперь ясно, я забыл про волатильность, это многое объясняет почему IDE так поступает.

Comment: Еще можете посмотреть интерфейс Callable(альтернатива Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

Полезно для набивания самому себе шишек, с последующим исследованием. В этом примере не хватает как минимум потокобезопасной *волатильной* коллекции, если потоков будет много:

```java
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

// Создаем поток
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        objects.add("new Object()");
    }
});
// Запускаем поток
t.start();
// Ждем, пока он отработает
t.join();

System.out.println(objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

Требование модификатора `final` тут не связано с мультипоточностью. Все дело в том, что переменные объявленные в теле метода перестают существовать при выходе из метода. Обойдемся без мультипоточности, для примера анонимный класс:

```
Runnable deferredGreeting() {

    String phrase = "is the answer";

    int answer = 42;

    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(answer + " " + phrase);
        }  
    };
}
```

При компиляции на старой версии java здесь будет ошибка, а компилятор java8 сам, не явно, проставит модификаторы `final` перед `String phrase` и `int answer`, все потому, что созданный `Runnable` вернется из метода и продолжит "жить", а локальные переменные уже перестанут существовать.

```
Runnable result = defferedGreepting(); // при вызове метода создались а затем уничтожились локальные переменные

result.run(); // А здесь будет запущена логика которая попытается сконструировать строку из локальных переменных.
```

Модификатор `final` гарантирует неизменность значения переменной, а значит в лямбду или, как в примере выше, в анонимный класс можно поместить копии значений. Т.е. захвата переменных не происходит, происходит захват значений, для строки значением будет указатель на строку, а для `int` само значение `42`.

```
final Object[] holder = new Object[1];
```

Это одно из возможных решений, `holder` содержит ссылку на массив аллоцированный в куче. Копия ссылки создается в анонимном классе, таким образом на массив будет существовать две ссылки, одна из переменной в методе, вторая из тела анонимного класса `new Runnable()`, когда произойдет выход из метода, первая ссылка будет уничтожена, но останется вторая и тогда GC не удалит массив `new Object[1]`. В свою очередь массив содержит ячейку в которую можно записать ссылку на результат.

Другое возможно решение использовать AtomicReference

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>();

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            result.set("Hello");
        }
    });
    // ... 
}
```

Обычно теперь так не пишут, потому как дальше возникнут проблемы с доступом к разделяемому ресурсу, вот как ты узнаешь что результат готов? В какой момент можно прочитать значение? Но это уже совсем другая история.